# Memory leak without memory leak

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I got Storyboard with a ViewController in NavigationController in TabBarController. 
This VC is presenting modal controller when user tapped "Logout" and then, when user Login one more time, dismissing that modal window. 
I clearly see that modal viewController beeng deinited when dismiss performed, but if i repeat login/logout sevaral times, i see that memory usage increases as much as i repeat login/logout. Tere is no data passed, no delegates, etc
Prifile -> Leak show no leaks but memory still disappear.
There are just simple three lines of code, whats wrong?

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func logoutTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
    let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")

    present(vc, animated: true) {
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
    }
}
```

Modal

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func authorizeTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

deinit {
    print("Deinit")
}
```

Here is a memory graph after several login/logouts

[image]

**UPD**

Before Deinit

[image]

After Deinit

[image]

UPD2: Zombies

[image]

Comment: Use “debug memory graph” button in Xcode and look at the objects in the left panel and see if you see any of your classes not getting released.

Comment: Yep, all good. I updated question with images of memory debuger

Comment: This is just saying that you still have one of each. When you run this again and again, are there any objects appearing (with increasing numbers) on the left panel? Also, I assume you don't have zombies turned on.

Comment: doesn't matter how much i repeat, there are always proper numbers. 
Yes you're right zombies was turned off. I activated it and got 283 issue ) Added image in question. 
What i got to do with that? In Profile->Zombies it shows nothing